# Expected to return a value at the end of arrow function array-callback-return

Tags: javascript, eslint

I have an eslint warning in my code `Expected to return a value at the end of arrow function  array-callback-return`

Here is the code

```
return (
      <div className={cx('houseMap')}>
        {templateProperties.template.map(({ component, field, children }, idx) => {
          if (properties[field.toLowerCase()]) {
            return this.buildComponent(idx, component, field, children)
          }
        })}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

How can I refactor that code to get rid of the warning?

Comment: Hi! Please do include the actual warning in your post :)

Comment: You are not returning anything outside of the if statement.

Comment: so how do i need to refactor it? Because the code is working properly

Answer (score 1):

You have path of code that does not return value. You need to provide some kind of return:

```js
return (
      <div className={cx('houseMap')}>
        {templateProperties.template.map(({ component, field, children }, idx) => {
          if (properties[field.toLowerCase()]) {
            return this.buildComponent(idx, component, field, children)
          }
          return "SOMETHING in case if arg is true"
        })}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Basically, this rule says all code paths must explicitly return some value.